# How to delete the rows in a dataframe with zero values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rowdeleting

I want to delete the rows that are having values which are all zeros.
This is how my data set looks like:

```
ChildBks YouthBks CookBks DoItYBks RefBks ArtBks
    1       0        1       0       0      0
    0       0        0       0       0      0
    1       1        0       0       0      1
    0       0        1       1       0      0
```

I want to have it like this

```
ChildBks YouthBks CookBks DoItYBks RefBks ArtBks
    1       0        1       0       0      0
    1       1        0       0       0      1
    0       0        1       1       0      0
```

How can we delete the second row as all the values in this rows are equal to zero.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `df[rowSums(df) > 0,]`

Comment: safer would be `df[rowSums(df != 0) > 0, ]` Or `df[rowSums(df == 0) != ncol(df), ]`

Answer (score 0):

if your data.frame is `df` then you can use

```
df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) all(x == 0)), ]
```

or equivalently you could use

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x != 0)), ]
```

Note that the solution suggested by Sotos in the comments is valid only if you have no negative values in your columns. If this is the case I think his solution is faster.